# Unstaged and uncommited files were lost from a folder on local repo

Tags: git, gitlab

I am fairly new to Git so I still do not completely understand how it works. I have a problem that some files disapeared from my local repositoy. Namely, I have not staged nor commited any files from this one folder and now I cannot find them anymore on my local repo. I have in the meantime pulled and merged data from the remote.

For example this is what I get aftering running show command:
 `git show HEAD:Data+analysis/compilation_data fatal: path 'Data+analysis/compilation_data' exists on disk, but not in 'HEAD'`

I hope these are good news and that I can still recover and find these files somewhere on my disk even though they are not recognized by git.

Since the lost files were not commited I cannot find the with reflog or log command as I usually retrive some lost files.
I checked out the folder using a basic file explorer to see if the files are there and noup there is nothing inside the folder besides the .Rhistory

Therefore, I am pretty much lost and unsure how to find these files.

Comment: If you never committed your work it will not be saved by git. You really really want to start committing your changes - that is the whole point of git. Have you just looked in the folder using a basic file explorer to see if you files are there ... (as opposed to running git show commands)? What is the output of git status?

Comment: The message even says "exists on disk" (but not in in HEAD). The files are still in your file system, why do you assume otherwise? Does `ls -a` not show them? `git show` will only show objects known to Git, especially if you explicitly tell it to show something from the `HEAD` commit.

Comment: ls -a shows only the following: ./  ../  .RData  .Rhistory

Comment: I checked out the folder using a basic file explorer to see if the files are there and noup there is nothing inside the folder besides the .Rhistory

Comment: after running git status, Only some recent untracked files are listed but none of the folder of interest

Comment: Are you in the correct directory? Because the Git error message specifically states "exists on disk". `ls- a` must show `.git` if you are in the root directory of your working tree, I don't see a `.git` directory in your output

Comment: I was in the folder of interest but when I run the command while being in the root directory i get the .git and  ./ ../ .git .gitignore .RData .Rhistory .Rproj.user/ Data+analysis/

Comment: There's your `Data+analysis/` folder. Nothing got lost

Comment: that is correct the folder is there but there are no files in the folder, it is empty. So, my issue is that I have the folder but all the files within the folder are gone. I want to retrieve the files if possible, back to be visible in my local repo

Comment: You can do a search for the files by name (on your whole computer, if necessary). Also you want to look inside your RecycleBin or Trash (if your OS has a feature like this). And you can attempt to use file recovery tools. I'm afraid Git won't be of much use if you have never staged or committed these files - Git will not have any version history that you could use to access these files.

Comment: Is this directory managed by a cloud syncing service, such as iCloud or Dropbox?  If so, that's likely the cause, and you should not do that, since it can cause corruption and data loss.